# find the Classification of discontinuities of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

In my assignment I have to find the Classification of discontinuities of the following function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x|x(\pi-x)|}$$

I wanted to start with the value $x=0$ because the function doesn't exist in that value.

I have to check if some  $L \in \Bbb R$ exists such that $$\lim  _{x \to 0} f(x)=L $$

I will use limits arithmetic now:

$$\lim _{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x|x(\pi-x)|}$$ $$=\lim _{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x} *\lim _{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x|x(\pi-x)|}$$ 
$$=1*  \lim _{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x|x(\pi-x)|}$$

Now I know that $x(x-\pi)$ is positive since $x\to0$, so I can "get rid" of the abusolute value here:
$$=1*  \lim _{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x*x(\pi-x)}$$
$$=1*  \lim _{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x}*\frac{1}{x(\pi-x)}$$
$$=1*1*\frac{1}{\pi}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\pi}$$

Therefore, the limit is $$=\frac{1}{\pi}$$

I am not sure about the part where I'm "canceling" the absolute value. Am I wrong there? is my solution correct?

Is my solution proves Removable discontinuity?

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you have a limit for $x=0^+$ and another one for $x=0^-$

Comment: That is what I thought, but didn't know how to prove...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$=\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{x}*\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{x|x(\pi-x)|}$$

At this step you made a mistake. It should have been

$$=\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{x}*\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{|x(\pi-x)|}$$

Take absolute value separately

$$\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{|x||(\pi-x)|}$$

$|(\pi-x)|$ is always positive

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim _{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{|x|}$$

we get

$$\pm \frac{1}{\pi}$$

Also why don't you verify these sorts of things on wolframalpha?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%5E2%2F%28x%7Cx+%28Pi+-+x%29%7C%29

Comment: Thank you! so there are two sides to that limit? Which means it's Jump discontinuity?

Comment: Yes____________